# IBM Notes asking for user id file during setup

Tags: ibm-domino, lotus-notes

I have a test Domino server and client machines. I have problem trying to setup IBM Notes on a client machine using the admin credential(e.g. John Doe). After putting Name (John Doe) and Server name, its asking for the user id file as shown below:

[image]

I've confirmed client machine is able to ping the domino server, also I was able to open the domino server web administrator on client browser with same credential. But one thing I observed during Note setup (in case its related), I was only able to connect using the hostname of domino server. It refused to connect using just the server name in the format: mydomino01/hrteam.

Earlier on, I setup IBM Notes on a Macbook with same credentials and without it prompting me for user id file, I put in the password and it was able to access domino server. I've found a user.id file in my Mac's IBM Notes Data, can I simply import this file into this new client's IBM Notes Data directory?

`Notes.ini` in my My Domino server:

```
Directory=/local/notesdata
KeyFileName=/local/notesdata/server.id
KeyFileName_Owner=CN=mydomino01/O=hrteam
CertifierIDFile=/local/notesdata/cert.id
MailServer=CN=mydomino01/O=hrteam
```

I'm confused about what to do next,how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, you can copy the id file from your Mac to this machine and then use that id file when IBM Notes asks for an id file.

Comment: Thank you, it connected just doing that. I was skeptical at first because I had tried this before with a client in vm connected as NAT and Host-Only. I guess it was a network issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the id file from your Mac to this machine and then use that id file when IBM Notes asks for an id file.

Comment: An off topic question: I want to enable the Data Access at Database level according to: https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Domino+Access+Services+9.0.1#action=openDocument&res_title=Enabling_Domino_Data_Service_on_a_database_das901&content=apicontent but I can't find database properties in Note client. Please do you know where it is? Its not mentioned in the documentation at all

Comment: It's on the last tab in the bottom of the database properties. It's called "Allow Domino Data Service".

Comment: You access the properties from File - Application - Properties

Comment: Sorry, I closed Note and when I restarted, I'm getting `Unable to find path to server` any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: I'm able to ping server but I when I try to open Mail, I get `Unable to find path to server`

Comment: Please ask a new question

Comment: I've asked here: https://serverfault.com/questions/891890/ibm-note-unable-to-find-path-to-server

Answer (score 0):

i have a question. My Notes i can ask for a reset password so i dont have to find an id file after i re initiate Notes. However, every time i try to re setup notes it asks me to find id file. My coworkers it asks for the temporary password and they log in. I already move logs, names, bookmarks, desktop8. I zap notes and no luck Is there a way to make Notes ask for password instead of id? Thank you in advance

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/539918)